# Getting a 302 server response when trying to upload a text onto the server

Tags: php, android, http, cpanel

The uploading functionality works fine if i connect to local host and upload a file .server side is in PHP. But I'm getting a 302 server response when trying to upload a text onto the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 302 response code may not be a problem, all the 3xx status codes just mean that there was success, but there was a redirect.  302 specifically means "Found" which usually indicates that there was a rewrite rule or something on the server side.

Check if your file actually did upload successfully, or if there is an error in the response you get - hopefully the 302 really is just a redirect indicator and not actually a failure.